# Project doesn't recognize cucumber-picocontainer dependency

Tags: java, maven, selenium, cucumber, picocontainer

I'm currently working on a java test framework with cucumber, JUnit and Selenium. I've already worked on projects like that, but I'm experiencing an issue on this one.

I'm trying to create a Context class that is a Singleton. I want to use cucumber-picocontainer to have this class accessible in every step definition class. I added the dependencies in my pom.xml, but every time I try to execute my tests, I have an exception that says : "NewLoginSteps doesn't have an empty constructor. If you need DI, put cucumber-picocontainer on the classpath". I tried to import the jars manually, but it didn't help.

Here is a sample of my configuration :

- pom.xml

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>


      <properties>
          <cucumber.version>1.2.4</cucumber.version>
          <selenium-java.version>2.39.0</selenium-java.version>
      </properties>
      <dependencies>
          <dependency>
              <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
              <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
              <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
              <scope>test</scope>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
              <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
              <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
              <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
              <scope>test</scope>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
              <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
              <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
              <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
              <scope>test</scope>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
              <groupId>junit</groupId>
              <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
              <version>4.11</version>
              <scope>test</scope>
          </dependency>
  </project>
  ```

TestContext.java :

```
public class TestContext {
    private static Map<String, String> siteLocations = new HashMap<String, String>();
    private static boolean initialized = false;
    private static boolean firstInitDone = false;
    private static WebDriver driver;
    private static boolean testsToRun = false;
    private static AutomatedTestMode modeAsEnum;

    @Before
    public void setUp(Scenario scenario) {
        initialize();
        Log.startTestCase(scenario.getName());
        afterAll();
    }
    ....
}
```

a step definition class :

```
public class NewLoginSteps extends NewSuperSteps {

    public NewLoginSteps(TestContext context){
        super(context);
    }


    @When("^I log in nova as \"([^\"]*)\" user with \"([^\"]*)\" \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void newLogin(String instance, String username, String password){
        Assert.assertEquals(true, false);

    }

    @Then("^The user is connected$")
    public void The_user_is_connected(){
        throw new PendingException();
    }

}
```

my superSepts class :

```
public class NewSuperSteps {
    protected TestContext context;
    public NewSuperSteps(TestContext context){
        this.context=context;
    }

}
```

Do you have an idea about what I've done wrong ? I've already used picocontainer in order to do the same thing and it was working.

Comment: i got a similar issue, did you by any chance found the way to resolve this?

Comment: @himawan_r No, my problem wasn't solved at the time. I changed a lot of things since then. And I'm not using picocontainer anymore

Comment: i followed Vacha Dave solution by making all info cukes version the same, it works for me :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I faced similiar issue.

The problem was in the version of the info cukes..You need to have the same version of all cucumber-* in your pom.xml.
 That solved the issue for me.

Comment: this is not the answer to the question. you should ask new if you does not find the answer in the community.

Comment: thanks @VachaDave, just tried your answer and it did the trick. this should be an accepted answer.

Comment: I can't really mark it as an accepted answer. As you can see in the sample of my pom.xml, my version of all the cucumber dependencies are managed by a single parameter --> hence, the same version

Comment: @NicolasG.Duvivier allright np, just wanted to let others that might find this issue to try this. the issue might be varies tough

Comment: @himawan_r As it solved similar issues for others, and I don't even have access to this code anymore. I accepted your answer

Comment: @NicolasG.Duvivier I have faced the same problem as you, This answer does not solve that problem. I don't think this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

info.cukes artifact is now move to io.cucumber. Every dependency related to cucumber should have same version number.

```
<properties>
    <io.cucumber.version>4.7.2</io.cucumber.version>
</properties>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>${io.cucumber.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>${io.cucumber.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Using PicoContainer to share state between steps in a scenario -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
        <version>${io.cucumber.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add below dependency to your pom.xml

```
<dependency>   
    <groupId>org.picocontainer</groupId>  
    <artifactId>picocontainer</artifactId>
    <version>2.14.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try it but I think I've already tried that. I'll keep you aware of the result.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following dependency worked for me,

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not include

```
<dependency>   
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>  
    <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

in addition to cucumber-junit and cucumber-picocontainer.

That was the problem on my project.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem exists even after giving the same version of all cucumber-* in your pom.xml. I downloaded all dependency jars and added in Module settings under the dependency tab. Now its working fine.

Answer (score -1):

Your project is complaining because cucumber needs beans to be injected but you don't have any framework to help with that. instead of using cucumber-pico container dependency, you should use cucumber-spring with the same version as your cucumber. it should fix the issue

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
     <artifactId>cucumber-spring</artifactId>
     <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
</dependency>
```